# org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type

Tags: java, android, ios, oracle

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

String Empcode="10743";
String password="IsaiVanan";

final String uri = "https://vtop9.vit.ac.in/vtoplogin/employeeLoginPost";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

MultiValueMap<String, String> postParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
postParams.add("userid",Empcode);
postParams.add("pwd",password);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<> (postParams,headers);
System.out.println("Try coming1..!");

ResponseEntity<UserValidation> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,entity, UserValidation.class);

System.out.print("result..."+result.getBody().getResponseMsg());
```

I did everything which i add dependency of rest api,
this witch i did response content in application/json still; it not working i find that solution only in some stackoverflow verify..!

```
public class UserValidation {

    private String responseMsg ;
    private Integer responseCode;
    public String getResponseMsg() {
        return responseMsg;
    }
    public void setResponseMsg(String responseMsg) {
        this.responseMsg = responseMsg;
    }
    public Integer getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }
    public void setResponseCode(Integer responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

}


org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/json]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
    at sample.doGet(sample.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

error occurs when i add jar files in project of build path, namely rest api jar, spring frameworks...

error shows and consult with everyone which they did know about rest api.

which someone please find the solution and get the corrected output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is not able to parse your request payload (LinkedMultiValueMap) to JSON. Please make sure that you use a converter that can do this. So your request is not sent to the target system.

Please read this for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

Comment: i am using in servlet is that possible which it do in servlet.? well this one is API i did it only in servlet and jsp is that possible

Comment: Yes, you are using a RestTemplate for user validation in a Servlet. Please read this guide to get more information about how to use Springs RestTemplate: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       headers.add("userid",Empcode);
       headers.add("pwd",password);
      
   
               HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
               
               
                ResponseEntity<UserValidation> result= restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,entity, UserValidation.class);

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [UserValidation] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]

Comment: No, it is the same error message, but another error. Please read that error messages carefully. Your application is not able to parse the response from the server. Please make sure that your response object is serializable.

Answer (score 4):

For retrieving a resource with `application/json` Accept Header, you need `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, which is one of the special `HttpMessageConverters`  which looks like you're missing.

Try adding below just after initializing `RestTemplate` as :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);
// carry on with your code
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
 private HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> makeExportRequestEntity(RequestObject requestObject ) throws IOException {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    bodyMap.add("DataOne", requestObject .getDataOne());
    bodyMap.add("DataTwo", requestObject .getDataTwo());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);

    return requestEntity;
}
```